# Supporting Long Values in Module Settings

Tags: virtocommerce

Following the guidance in the [documentation for managed module settings](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Managing+Module+Settings), I have created some settings for my custom module.

For the most part this is working fine, but I have one setting that expects an API key for a 3rd party service, and that key is > 512 characters.  This results in a validation failure when I try to save the setting because by default all the settings use the ShortTextValue property.  How can I use LongTextValue for this particular setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long text values you can use the "text" value type:

```
<valueType>text</valueType>
```

Though the UI was missing the input filed for this value type until version 2.4.593.

P.S. Documentation has been updated.